# Delete inoperable stackset in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I am super confused at the moment and struggling to work with AWS. I created a copilot app, created the services and later wanted to delete it. I deleted some stuff manually it seems and now I am left with an inoperable stackset that I cannot remove it. As the stack has to be empty but the stack instance is inoperable so I cant do anything to it

[image]

I have two roles, execution and admin, this is the execution role

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "cloudformation:*",
                "s3:*",
                "sns:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Sid": "StackSetRequiredPermissions"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "kms:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Sid": "ManageKMSKeys"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "ecr:DescribeImageScanFindings",
                "ecr:GetLifecyclePolicyPreview",
                "ecr:CreateRepository",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:ListTagsForResource",
                "ecr:ListImages",
                "ecr:DeleteLifecyclePolicy",
                "ecr:DeleteRepository",
                "ecr:SetRepositoryPolicy",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "ecr:DescribeImages",
                "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
                "ecr:GetLifecyclePolicy",
                "ecr:TagResource"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Sid": "ManageECRRepos"
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is the admin

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "cloudformation:*",
                "s3:*",
                "sns:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Sid": "StackSetRequiredPermissions"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "kms:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Sid": "ManageKMSKeys"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "ecr:DescribeImageScanFindings",
                "ecr:GetLifecyclePolicyPreview",
                "ecr:CreateRepository",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:ListTagsForResource",
                "ecr:ListImages",
                "ecr:DeleteLifecyclePolicy",
                "ecr:DeleteRepository",
                "ecr:SetRepositoryPolicy",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "ecr:DescribeImages",
                "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
                "ecr:GetLifecyclePolicy",
                "ecr:TagResource"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Sid": "ManageECRRepos"
        }
    ]
}
```

They don't look quite right as I messed around with them to get this to work, but no luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deleting the stackset and retaining the stack was the way to go. Afterwords I could manually delete the stack.

Comment: THANK YOU - I've been struggling to delete an inoperable stackset for months, I've given up so many times. I never would've thought retaining the stack would've been the way to go.